# t-SNE and normalization / standardization

Tags: normalization, standardization, tsne

I have 7 parameters with different scales. If I understand correctly, before applying t-SNE or other dimension reduction methods I should apply a standardization or normalization method on my parameters. The classical methods are z-standardization or the min-max method. However, the t-SNE algorithm I use is an implementation of the Barnes-Hut t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding and seems to use it's own normalization method. Basically, it calculates the mean value column by column and subtracts it from the corresponding column to center it around the mean value. Then the whole matrix is divided by the largest absolute value.

I never heard of this normalization method and I'm wondering what would be the right approach? Using z-standardization or min-max and then applying the t-SNE normalization method? Just apply the t-SNE normalization method or just use z-standardization or min-max?

Depending on the normalization method, results vary very much.